How to Check Testnet Liquidity on Uniswap for Arbitrum Sepolia?
I’m building a swapping application that leverages the Uniswap swap router contract and I need to test it on the Arbitrum Sepolia testnet. However, in the Uniswap UI, I can only see options for the Ethereum Sepolia testnet and Unichain, but there's no explicit visibility into Arbitrum Sepolia.

Is there a way to check or confirm if there is liquidity on Uniswap for Arbitrum Sepolia?
If not, how can I simulate or test swaps on this network without existing liquidity?


I believe if your code runs well on Sepolia testnet, it will run well on any other chain that Uniswap supports.
If you want to build yourself on local network. You can take a look at Uniswap docs or some video tutorial:
https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/guides/local-environment
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0OhfGLh4nc

Thank you for the guidance mate  , i will try that out
